# Why the Task doesn't show canceled status

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I am testing a simple console application created on Linqpad, idea is to have assured understanding of the working of `Task` and create a logic which works, when `Task` is **completed, faulted or Canceled**. I want to execute a logic only when Task is completed but not faulted or canceled.

```
void Main()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1000));

    Task t = Task.Run(() => Work(),cts.Token);
    try
    {
        t.Wait();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    ("Completed :: " + t.IsCompleted).Dump();
    ("Canceled :: " + t.IsCanceled).Dump();
    ("Faulted :: " + t.IsFaulted).Dump();
}

public async Task Work()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

Following are the issues:

1. I am able to confidently figure out the Completed and Faulted states, but even when in my view this code should lead to Task cancellation, the value of `IsCanceled` property is always false.
2. Ideally when the Task is faulted, even though I am silently capturing the exception in a try catch block, it should show `IsCompleted` as false, but it always remain true, currently Linqpad doesn't have **continue on error option**, but I am assuming, it would turn false if I can continue on error

Comment: Cancellation is *co-operative*. Your task ignored your cancellation token and instead chose to run to completion. Therefore, it wasn't cancelled.

Comment: What modification shall I do to get this working and is my other understanding right, if the exception propagates, then it should be faulted not completed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am able to confidently figure out the Completed and Faulted states, but even when in my view this code should lead to Task cancellation, the value of IsCanceled property is always false.

There is no automatism in cancellation. You are passing `CancellationToken` to `Task.Run`. If cancellation would occur while the task is starting, the start process would be interrupted by cancellation. Once the task is running, it is the task's method's responsibility to check the cancellation token. `Wait` is not doing that. It does not even know of the cancellation token. Hence, the task can never turn into the canceled state.

This is how you would observe cancellation:

```
void Main()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1000));

    Task t = Task.Run(() => Work(cts.Token),cts.Token);
    try
    {
        t.Wait();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    ("Completed :: " + t.IsCompleted).Dump();
    ("Canceled :: " + t.IsCanceled).Dump();
    ("Faulted :: " + t.IsFaulted).Dump();
}

public async Task Work(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Delay(3000, token);
}
```

> Ideally when the Task is faulted, even though I am silently capturing the exception in a try catch block, it should show IsCompleted as false, but it always remain true

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted.aspx):

> IsCompleted will return true when the task is in one of the three final states: RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive set of details and answering all the questions

Answer (score 5):

Others have noted that your code is not observing the `CancellationToken`, and that's why the task is not being cancelled.

I'll answer this part of the question:

> I want to execute a logic only when Task is completed but not faulted or canceled.

To do this, put your logic after you `await` the task:

```
await t;
// Your logic here.
```

Using `IsCanceled` / `IsFaulted` / `IsCompleted` for control flow is a code smell.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary for important details, in fact that's how my code is, I am having number of different `Task<T>` wrapped up inside `List<Task>` and I have called `await Task.WhenAll(TaskList)`, I didn't realize that this would throw up any exception in the underlying tasks to the caller, I thought this would silently embed the exception and I need to explicitly figure out which Tasks contain the valid Result and which one are faulted / canceled, but as you have clarified, this is a incorrect when await is used to unwrap

Answer (score 2):

You did not pass the `CancellationToken` to the `Task.Delay` method, so nothing had to be cancelled. 
The token you pass in `Task.Run(xxx)` prevents the work from ever being started if the token has an outstanding cancellation. But your token is cancelled after 1 second, that is long after the call to `Task.Run`.

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000));

    Task t = Task.Run(() => Work(cts.Token), cts.Token);
    try
    {
        t.Wait();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    ("Completed :: " + t.IsCompleted).Dump();
    ("Canceled :: " + t.IsCanceled).Dump();
    ("Faulted :: " + t.IsFaulted).Dump();
}

public async Task Work(CancellationToken t)
{
    await Task.Delay(3000, t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, appreciate, it helps